# Do anybody know, why this JavaScript program (DIGITAL TIMER) is not working, when I click it to start the timer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, clock

Do anybody know, why this JavaScript program (DIGITAL TIMER) is not working, when I click it to start the timer?

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer-container">
        <h1 id="timer-display">00:00:00</h1>
    </div> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
body{
    font-family: "Software Tester 7";
    background-color: black;
}

.timer-container{
    background-color: yellow-green;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 19%;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

And this is the JavaScript code:

```
var timeBegan = null; // did the clock start?
var timeStopped = null; // at what time was the timer stopped?
var stoppedDuration = 0; // how long was the timer stopped?
var startInterval = null; // this is needed to stop the startInterval() method
var flag = false; // to control the start/stop of the timer

const timerContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("timer-container")[0];

timerContainer.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    if(!flag)
    {
        startTimer();
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        stopTimer();
        flag = false;
    }
})
function startTimer()
{
    if(timeBegan === null)
        timeBegan = new Date();

    if(timeStopped !== null)
        stoppedDuration += (new Date() - timeStopped);

    startInterval = setInterval(clockRunning, 10);
}

function stopTimer()
{
    timeStopped = new Date();
    clearInterval(startInterval);
}
function clockRunning()
{   
var currentTime = new Date
var timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - timeBegan - stoppedDuration);

var minutes = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
var milliseconds = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

milliseconds = Math.floor(milliseconds/10);

document.getElementById("timer.display").innerHTML = 
(minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes:minutes) + ":" +
(seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds:seconds) + ":" +
(milliseconds = milliseconds < 10 ? '0' + milliseconds:milliseconds);
}
```

I hope someone can really help me with my issue.

It is from this YouTube tutorial: " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bvutuhUxHY&ab_channel=codefoxx ".

Thank you soo much for a soon answer :)

Comment: Move the `const timerContainer` into the body of your function.

Comment: Did you check your developer console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very small mistake

Your id of clock is `timer-display` but on the `clockRunning`  function you have used it as `timer.display`

everything else is working very fine
Click on the timer to start running and click again to stop timer,

Note: if  you want to start timer by default then call startTimer function on body onload

```js
var timeBegan = null; // did the clock start?
var timeStopped = null; // at what time was the timer stopped?
var stoppedDuration = 0; // how long was the timer stopped?
var startInterval = null; // this is needed to stop the startInterval() method
var flag = false; // to control the start/stop of the timer

const timerContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("timer-container")[0];

timerContainer.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    if(!flag)
    {
        startTimer();
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        stopTimer();
        flag = false;
    }
})
function startTimer()
{
    if(timeBegan === null)
        timeBegan = new Date();

    if(timeStopped !== null)
        stoppedDuration += (new Date() - timeStopped);

    startInterval = setInterval(clockRunning, 10);
}

function stopTimer()
{
    timeStopped = new Date();
    clearInterval(startInterval);
}
function clockRunning()
{   
var currentTime = new Date
var timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - timeBegan - stoppedDuration);

var minutes = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds();
var milliseconds = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

milliseconds = Math.floor(milliseconds/10);

document.getElementById("timer-display").innerHTML = 
(minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes:minutes) + ":" +
(seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds:seconds) + ":" +
(milliseconds = milliseconds < 10 ? '0' + milliseconds:milliseconds);
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: "Software Tester 7";
    background-color: black;
}

.timer-container{
    background-color: yellow-green;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 19%;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="timer-container">
        <h1 id="timer-display">00:00:00</h1>
    </div> 
    
</body>
</html>
```